# Phd defense jury in Belgium

Tags: phd, defense, belgium

I have been invited to be an external jury member for a PhD defense at a Belgian university. Apart from reimbursement of my travel expenses, am I going to be paid for this work? In UK (where I am based), there will be payment for external examiners. It would be embarrassing for me to ask them directly:)

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 5):

On the continent, my understanding is that it’s considered part of “service duties” and thus while travel is (often) compensated for, your time is not.

Comment: So your answer doesn't apply to Cyprus or Malta?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi That's a pars pro toto expression meaning "Europe minus Ireland and the UK (but including other islands)", similar to using "England" for the UK.

Comment: @henning I know, I just find this expression a bit dumb. As if the British isles formed one homogeneous group, and "the continent" another.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi 51,9% of the Brits think so. ;)

Comment: @henning I hadn't realized that Brexit meant that the Republic of Ireland would leave the EU too. (Besides, my main point is that "the continent" is not a homogeneous block. I know, I'm reading too much into a joke.)

Comment: @Najib Idrissi I always felt the expression "the continent" carries a very British perspective (splendid isolation and all) and is used in the UK more often than on ... the continent. (But perhaps I should stop cluttering the comments.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75545/discussion-between-henning-and-najib-idrissi).

Comment: @henning That's for sure. In fact, I'm pretty sure that anyone on "the continent" who says "the continent"  would include the UK in "the continent".