# PhD Defense Belgium

Tags: phd, defense, belgium

I received an invitation to serve as a member of a PhD defense examiners' board at a Belgian university. While they have offered to cover travel expenses, there is no mention of remuneration. I am curious if this lack of payment is standard practice in Belgium, as examiners in the UK and Scandinavian universities are compensated for their work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phd defense jury in Belgium](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107569/phd-defense-jury-in-belgium)

Comment: Source that examiners in the U.K. are compensated for their work please.

Comment: I have been in 4 UK universities, and as far as I know, none compensate examiners for their work. I believe its like reviewing a paper, "part of the job". I do not know 100%, but never heard of it.

Comment: That's strange. I have received remuneration as an external examiner in the UK. I know colleagues who have received it too. I didn't know that Belgium offers none (or perhaps not the case in other European unis).

Comment: Most universities do not provide renumeration. I believe the outlier here are Scandinavian universities, not Belgium. That said, even if they do provide a renumeration, it's not sure they would mention this in their initial email.